# How do I do this bit manipulation? Shift left followed by a subtract?

Tags: assembly, mips, computer-science

> For the register values shown above, what is the value of $t2 for the following sequence of instructions?

```
$t0 = 0xAAAAAAAA and $t1 = 0x12345678
```

commands:

```
                   sll  $t2, $t0, 4
                   andi $t2, $t2, −1
```

So a shift left of 4 is like adding 4 0s to the beginning.

So $t0 in bits is `1010 1010 1010 1010 1010 1010 1010 1010`
after a shift left it's: `1010 1010 1010 1010 1010 1010 1010 0000`

Then if I subtract 1 it's... what? How do I do this?

Comment: For questions involving assembly language, it is a good idea to tag the question with `assembly` and with the architecture (it looks like this may be `mips`).

Comment: Also, the second instruction is not subtraction.  It is an `andi` instruction.  So you should research what the `andi` instruction does (hint: it is a type of `and` instuction), and how negative values are represented in your architecture (hint: research _two's complement_)